# Pop up box Error

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I click cancel on the pop up message it still deletes the record and I don't know why.

```
<tr>
    <td class="recordCells">
        <div align="center">
            <a onclick="confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" href="deleterecord.php?ID=<?php echo $row_rsInventory['ID']; ?>">
                <img src="../images/x.png" align="absmiddle">
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You doesn't return the value of the confirm box :

```
<tr>
    <td class="recordCells">
        <div align="center">
            <a onclick="return(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?'))" href="deleterecord.php?ID=<?php echo $row_rsInventory['ID']; ?>">
                <img src="../images/x.png" align="absmiddle">
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually there is a problem of "href = deleterecord.php file" in anchor tag so you can use code something like that:

```
jQuery(".confirm_click").click(function(){
    var check = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
    if(check == true){
      // Action - Record deleted
      var url= jQuery(this).attr("url");
      jQuery(location).attr('href',url);      
    }else{
      // Action - none
    }
  });
```

Html code:-

```
        <a class="confirm_click" href="" url="deleterecord.php?ID=<?php echo $row_rsInventory['ID']; ?>">
            <img src="../images/x.png" align="absmiddle">
        </a>
```

or you can send me a part of code on "mohit.tiwari@techinfini.com" and i'll make it in proper way.